# Two divs at equal distances from each other and page edge

Tags: css, html, position, margin

I'd like to have two dividers, side by side, of different widths at equal distances away from each and away from the edges of the page *depending on the screen size*.

So the code looks like this,

```
<div id="bodymain">

    <div id="main">

    </div>

    <div id="sidebartop">

    </div>

</div>

            #bodymain{
            position:absolute;
            margin-top:100px;
            margin-left:30px;
            margin-right:30px;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            height:1000px;
            background-color:white;
            z-index:0;
            }

            #main{
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            float:right;
            margin-top:30px;
            margin-bottom:30px;
            margin-right:30px;
            margin-left:auto;
            height:940px;
            width:700px;
            background-color:red;
            z-index:999;
            }

            #sidebartop{
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;
            margin-top:30px;
            margin-bottom:30px;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-left:30px;
            height:100px;
            width:200px;
            background-color:blue;
            z-index:999;
            }
```

Basically, I want the two dividers to auto detect the size of the screen and adjust to it correctly and be a certain distance from each side their respective edge of the screen, while maintaining a distance of at least 50px in-between. The size of the two dividers themselves do not matter; what matters is there distance from the edges of the screen, their distance from each other, and that the div on the left is supposed to be about 1/3 the width of the div on the right.

Sorry if this worded poorly, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write out what I want at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess so you're looking for a responsive website. Google for some framework that'll make your work easier and faster. I'd suggest you to take a look at [**Twitter Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com/), CSS Framework that's designed for a good responsive layout.

With the help of Bootstrap 3 you can design your website in a responsive way you wised for.

A simple [**Responsive Design**](http://jsfiddle.net/RpwGs/) using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

With twitter Bootstrap 3 you don't need to track the screen size as it does it for us.

You just need to add this meta tag in your head tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

And just assign some class or div to the element and give the margin you required on some certain size with `col-xs-*` `col-sm-*` `col-md-*` `col-lg-*` where col refers to the column and `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` refers to `extra small`, `small`, `medium` and `large` respectively.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Smbmy/

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1, .col2 {
    width: 605px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    height: 1000px;
}

.col2 {
    width: 305px;
    background: blue;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Hard to figure out exactly what you mean and for what purpose the layout is for?