# What css rules would you use to support smaller screens and resizing?

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

I'm currently having problems with resizing the window which cuts off a lot of the page and the elements which are positioned relatively to the document fly off the page.
Heres what it looks like:

Normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0bpY.png

Minimized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlVTb.png

scrolled to the end while minimized:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW5Q7.png

I either want the blue elements to go right to end even if it's minimized (It's width:100%) or have the elements resize proportionally to the window and fit everything in (everything is positioned relatively to the document)

css:

```
 body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#headr {
        background-image:url(../images/top%20bg.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:400px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:-100;
        overflow:hidden;
}

#lgo {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:33%;
    margin-top:80px;
} 

#nav {
    background-image:url(../images/nav%20bar.png);
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
    width:!important;
    height:99px;
}

#listone {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:570px;
    top:25px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navlist {
    display:inline;
    font-size:33px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position:static;
}

#searchb {
    background-image:url(../images/search.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:1350px;
    margin-top:-85px;
}

#searchb form {
    display:inline;
}
#searchbar {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:60px;
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    outline:none;
    font-size:24px;
}

.searchsubmit {
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:400px;
    width:30px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Html:

```
    <body>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="listone">
<li class="navlist">Home</li>
<li class="navlist">Portfolio</li>
<li class="navlist">Prices</li>
<li class="navlist">Contact</li>

</ul>
<div id="searchb">
<form>
<input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
<input type="image" class="searchsubmit" src="images/searchicon.png" value="">
</form></div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="headr">
<!--<img src="images/head logo.png" id="lgo"> -->
</div>
```

Comment: use @media to set up the minimum size, this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width

Comment: for @media, do i have to repeat my code each time and change it each time to fit the screen site specified under each @media?

Answer (score 0):

@Joe - I guess you're looking a responsive design. I'd suggest you to get along with [**Twitter Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com/). CSS Framework that takes care of the window size. You just need to make some `div` classes to make it responsive.

Getting along with framework will make it easier and faster for your develop the page and [**Twitter Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com/) does it for us.

Here's another [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139914/two-divs-at-equal-distances-from-each-other-and-page-edge/20140195#20140195) where the same answer's been given.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have to sepcifiy for each size you want, you would than write the css for the under media like you would any other css file. Here is an example

```
    /*if the width is over 768px the background will turn blue*/
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
        body { 
            background:blue;
        }
    }

    /*if the width is under 768px the background will turn yellow*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 769px){
        body {
            background:yellow;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to rewrite the properties that tou wish to change at each breakpoint. The cascading properties of CSS are important here, so you shuld pay attention to specificity and order of your selectors so as to achieve the expected result being DRY.

If you really want to support multiple screensizes you should take a look at responsive webdesign. Substituting your px to em is one example of what you wolud be doing.